# Collapse rows with consecutive TRUE values into a single row in R

Tags: r, database, dataframe, group-by

Consider the following dataframe.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),
                 Value = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE))
```

I want to transform `df` into `df'` such that every sequence of `TRUE` values in `Value` is collapsed into a single row, with their respective `ID`s being now the ID of the first True and the ID of the last. For the data frame above, we should get

```
ID    |   Value
---------------
1         FALSE
(2, 3)    TRUE
4         FALSE
(5, 8)    TRUE
```

I have no particular interest in the resulting type of `ID` (factor, string, whatever). How can I achieve this? I have tried mutating the data frame using `dplyr`'s `mutate` function, but I could not find the correct function to use inside `mutate`. I am aware that if I were able to assign a different `group` to each sequence of True values (in other words, if I could apply the intermediate transformation from

```
ID    |   Value
---------------
1         FALSE
2         TRUE
3         TRUE
4         FALSE
5         TRUE
6         TRUE
7         TRUE
8         TRUE
```

to

```
ID   |   Value    | Group
------------------------
1         FALSE     0
2         TRUE      1
3         TRUE      1
4         FALSE     0
5         TRUE      2
6         TRUE      2
7         TRUE      2
8         TRUE      2
```

the task would be much easier. But I haven't find a way to group by identifying sequences of values! Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need the intermediate part? I believe this though pocess is falliable. Better to directly move from the original df to the final df without going through the intermediate step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would calculate the groups by ticking the counter is the value is false or if the lagged value is false.

```
library(tidyverse)

df |>
     mutate(grp = cumsum(!Value | !lag(Value, default = TRUE))) |>
     group_by(grp)|>
     summarise(ID = ifelse(n() == 1, as.character(ID),
                           paste0("(", first(ID), ", ", last(ID), ")")),
               Value = first(Value))
```

EDIT
Here is a step by step for the logic:

First, we evaluate `!Value`

```r
df |> mutate(grp = !Value)
#>   ID Value   grp
#> 1  1 FALSE  TRUE
#> 2  2  TRUE FALSE
#> 3  3  TRUE FALSE
#> 4  4 FALSE  TRUE
#> 5  5  TRUE FALSE
#> 6  6  TRUE FALSE
#> 7  7  TRUE FALSE
```

For ease of visuals (bools can be tough to look at like this, we can wrap the expression in `+()` to evaluate as a binary.

```r
df |> mutate(grp = `+`(!Value))
#>   ID Value grp
#> 1  1 FALSE   1
#> 2  2  TRUE   0
#> 3  3  TRUE   0
#> 4  4 FALSE   1
#> 5  5  TRUE   0
#> 6  6  TRUE   0
#> 7  7  TRUE   0
```

From this we can see that everywhere that has `Value = FALSE` gets a 1 and `Value = TRUE` gets a 0. we can calculate the cumulative sum (i.e., `cumsum` to count every time we encounter a 1 (i.e., a `Value = FALSE`).

```r
df |> mutate(grp = cumsum(`+`(!Value)))
#>   ID Value grp
#> 1  1 FALSE   1
#> 2  2  TRUE   1
#> 3  3  TRUE   1
#> 4  4 FALSE   2
#> 5  5  TRUE   2
#> 6  6  TRUE   2
#> 7  7  TRUE   2
```

Here we see that every time `Value = False` `grp` goes up by one. We can also notice that our logic does not encapsulate the grouping correctly. The `Value=TRUE` get lumped in with the previous `Value=FALSE`, but we want them in their own group. We can add an additional logic to the expression to take care of that. For example, if the last value was false, then we also want to tick the group up one number.

```r
df |> mutate(grp = cumsum(`+`(!Value| !lag(Value, default = TRUE))))
#>   ID Value grp
#> 1  1 FALSE   1
#> 2  2  TRUE   2
#> 3  3  TRUE   2
#> 4  4 FALSE   3
#> 5  5  TRUE   4
#> 6  6  TRUE   4
#> 7  7  TRUE   4
```

Notice now, that the groups are exactly as we want them. We want every false group to be its own thing and all consevutive TRUE's to be their own thing. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the role of the `cumsum` function here? Thanks

Comment: I updated the question to add some clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(df, Group = consecutive_id(Value))
```

Output:

```
  ID Value Group
1  1 FALSE     1
2  2  TRUE     2
3  3  TRUE     2
4  4 FALSE     3
5  5  TRUE     4
6  6  TRUE     4
7  7  TRUE     4
```

The above code assigns a separate group to each consecutive Boolean in `Value`, if you'd like to only count `TRUE` groups you could try:

```
mutate(df, Group = (consecutive_id(Value) - cumsum(!Value)) * Value)
```

Output:

```
  ID Value Group
1  1 FALSE     0
2  2  TRUE     1
3  3  TRUE     1
4  4 FALSE     0
5  5  TRUE     2
6  6  TRUE     2
7  7  TRUE     2
```

I've overlooked you seemed to have indicated your desired output in the first table. Not to be completely redundant, here's another variation on the other answers:

```
df %>%
  group_by(group = consecutive_id(Value), Value)%>%
  summarise(ID = paste(unique(c(first(ID), last(ID))), collapse = ', '), .groups = 'drop')
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
  group Value ID   
  <int> <lgl> <chr>
1     1 FALSE 1    
2     2 TRUE  2, 3 
3     3 FALSE 4    
4     4 TRUE  5, 7
```

Comment: Note that your final output is close but not quite there. Only the first and last ID per group should be kept. Great use of consecutive_id though. I've never seen that one.

Comment: Thanks @AndS., corrected now. Yes, `consecutive_id` is a rather recent addition to `dplyr` (from February this year if I'm not mistaken).

Answer (score 1):

With `data.table`, you luckily will have `rleid` to take care of the run length

```
setDT(df)[
    ,
    .(
        ID = list(unique(range(ID))),
        Value = unique(Value)
    ),
    .(grp = rleid(Value))
]
```

which gives

```
   grp  ID Value
1:   1   1 FALSE
2:   2 2,3  TRUE
3:   3   4 FALSE
4:   4 5,7  TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `chop` from tidyr after creating the groups:

```
df %>%
   group_by(group = consecutive_id(Value))%>%
   chop(ID)

# A tibble: 4 × 3
# Groups:   group [4]
  Value group          ID
  <lgl> <int> <list<dbl>>
1 FALSE     1         [1]
2 TRUE      2         [2]
3 FALSE     3         [1]
4 TRUE      4         [3]
```

Since you claimed you are not interested in what happens to the `ID` column, you could also do:

```
df %>%
   group_by(group = consecutive_id(Value), Value)%>%
   summarise(ID = toString(ID), .groups = 'drop') # ID = list(ID)

# A tibble: 4 × 3
  group Value ID     
  <int> <lgl> <chr>  
1     1 FALSE 1      
2     2 TRUE  2, 3   
3     3 FALSE 4      
4     4 TRUE  5, 6, 7
```

---

```
df %>%
   group_by(group = consecutive_id(Value), Value)%>%
   summarise(ID = list(ID), .groups = 'drop')

# A tibble: 4 × 3
  group Value ID       
  <int> <lgl> <list>   
1     1 FALSE <dbl [1]>
2     2 TRUE  <dbl [2]>
3     3 FALSE <dbl [1]>
4     4 TRUE  <dbl [3]>
```